# How can I test multistep forms with Capybara & Minitest?

Tags: ruby, testing, sinatra, capybara, minitest

I have a single page Sinatra app that has a multistep form/wizard interface. If I want to test the form with Capybara, will need to repeat all the steps for each test? I'm hoping to avoid something like this:

```
it "visits the home page" do 
  vist "/"
  page.should have_content('foo')
end

it "clicks the first button" do 
  vist "/"
  page.should have_content('foo')
  button_click("Next")
end

it "clicks the second button" do 
  vist "/"
  page.should have_content('foo')
  button_click("Next")
  page.should_have_content('bar')
end

it "clicks the third button" do 
  vist "/"
  page.should have_content('foo')
  button_click("Next")
  page.should_have_content('bar')
  button_click("Next")
end
```

I found an article about [nested tests using RSpec and Capybara](http://tirdadc.github.io/blog/2014/09/11/nested-feature-tests-with-capybara-and-rspec/), but haven't been able to get a similar technique to work with Minitest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some research for you, and I'll share with you what I've found.

In order for doing this, you should consider "converting" your `Minitest` tests, to [specs](http://www.rubyinside.com/a-minitestspec-tutorial-elegant-spec-style-testing-that-comes-with-ruby-5354.html). This gives you access for similar syntax, as `RSpec`'s - `describe` with capability of nesting them.

*I'll simplify the code to provide example, but it should be clear where to put your logic.*

Let's check couple examples.

1). Let's do some simple test for `Array`:

```
require "minitest/autorun"

describe Array do
  before do
    @arr = []
  end

  describe "when initialized" do
    it "is empty" do
      @arr.length.must_equal 0
    end
  end
end
```

This should pass, nothing really fancy here.

2). Let's add another `describe`, nested to one we have:

```
describe Array do
  before do
    @arr = []
  end

  describe "when initialized" do
    it "is empty" do
      @arr.length.must_equal 0
    end

    describe "when element added" do
      it "length reflects the change" do
        @arr << "a"
        @arr.length.must_equal 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This also works - an element has been added to the array, and its `length` indicates that properly.

3). Let's try nesting another block. We're hoping, that `@arr << "a"` will be preserved, so if we add another element, `@arr.length` will be 2. Let's see:

```
describe Array do
  before do
    @arr = []
  end

  describe "when initialized" do
    it "is empty" do
      @arr.length.must_equal 0
    end

    describe "when element added" do
      it "length reflects the change" do
        @arr << "a"
        @arr.length.must_equal 1
      end

      describe "when another element added" do
        it "length also reflects the change" do
          @arr << "b"
          p @arr
          @arr.length.must_equal 2
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`describe` is nested within another `describe` - *as we would do for RSpec*, but unfortunately, it seems that the result of `@arr << "a"` is not preserved, and the nested `describe`'s `@arr.length` is also 1.

I have left `p @arr` in the code, so you can easily see in your console what is currently stored in `@arr`.

Definitely not what we expected... Let's try something *crazy* then...

4). Let's nest `describe` within... `it`:

```
describe Array do
  before do
    @arr = []
  end

  describe "when initialized" do
    it "is empty" do
      @arr.length.must_equal 0
    end

    describe "when element added" do
      it "length reflects the change" do
        @arr << "a"
        @arr.length.must_equal 1

        describe "when another element added" do
          it "length also reflects the change" do
            @arr << "b"
            p @arr
            @arr.length.must_equal 2
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Well, it turns out, that this is completely valid and it behaves exactly as we expected! (Again, `p @arr` left here so you an check in console what is currently stored in `@arr`).

To be honest - I didn't check that with `Capybara`, but this simple example is quite promising. Try modifying your code accordingly, so in your specs the `Capybara` interactions are implemented.

Let me be clear about provided solution: **I strongly advise agains** this approach:

- Specs like this are difficult to read - and in result - difficult to maintain.
- This is considered bad pattern. *Next* steps **should not** rely on result of *previous* steps.

If you want to test your contoller properly, you should try something similar to this (this is *pseudo code* just to illustrate idea):

*Test for step 1*

```
post "/url-to-my-form", { params_step_1: { ... } }
```

*Test for step 2*

```
post "/url-to-my-form", { params_step_1: { ... }, params_step_2: { ... } }
```

With this approach is very easy to see what `params` are `post`ed, thus it's easier to test against eg. violations of any rules (empty values, invalid email, etc...).

Hope that helps! Good Luck!