# How to test Cocoon gem's nested forms with Capybara and Minitest in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, capybara-webkit, cocoon-gem

Is it possible to use Minitest and Capybara to test multi-step forms in Rails? All of the examples I've read online and in Stackoverflow are using Rspec. For instance, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886694/how-can-i-test-multistep-forms-with-capybara-minitest).

It seems like this should be something that is possible to do in Minitest though. I'm trying to test a nested form that uses the Cocoon gem and looks like this:

Before clicking the "New Option" button:
[image: first step in the cocoon gem form]

After clicking the "New Option" button:
[image: Second step in the cocoon gem form]

But, my test keeps failing at this step:

```
click_link 'New Option'
```

If I add 'save_and_open_page' after `click_link 'New Option'` the browser shows that field that should be revealed by `click_link 'New Option'`. It works when I test it manually on my development server though. This `New Option` button is generated by Cocoon with this:

```
<%= link_to_add_association 'New Option', f, :options %>
```

So that leads me to believe that it's not finding the field on the next step because javacript is not working in Capybara and Minitest. But I'm not sure.

I have `Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit` in my `test_helper.rb` file, so the javascript driver should be working

Is this a problem with Minitest? Or am I doing something wrong in my test? If I view source on the page that is generated by `save_and_open_page` I can see the hidden fields in the `New Option` link tag. Here's what that looks like:

[image]

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184690/testing-fields-added-dynamically-by-cocoon-using-rspec-and-capybara), it seems like I need to do something like this:

click_link "New Option"
first("input[name='product[options_attributes][new_options][name]']").set("New Option Name")

But that gives me the error:

```
Capybara::ExpectationNotMet: expected to find css "input[name='product[options_attributes][new_options][name]']" at least 1 time but there were no matches
```

It seems like there's something wrong with Minitest & Capybara testing Javascript because it seems to fail at the "New Option" link and not after that. I can't tell if it's a problem with Javascript related to Minitest and Capybara or if I'm not accessing the field properly in Minitest.

Comment: You can do anything with minitest you can do with RSpec - just the assertion/expectation syntaxes are different.  Cocoons nested forms require JS on the page, so you need to be using a driver with Capybara that supports JS - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#drivers. Are you actually using `capybara-webkit` as the driver like your tags indicate (It's obsolete, equivalent to a 7 or 8 year old browser and won't run modern JS)? If so - switch to selenium with chrome so you can actually see what is happening in the browser when the test runs.

Comment: "But, my test keeps failing at this step:" what's the error there? you should show your test too.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Thanks. `capybara-webkit` was indeed the problem. Going to post all the changes required to get the test working. Appreciate you pointing this out.

Comment: @LeeMcAlilly you’re welcome - you may also want to look at the Apparition driver which has most of the Capybara-WebKit extra features - but it isn’t yet at V1 so there are a few rough edges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Thomas Walpole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2709090/thomas-walpole) for pointing out that `capybara-webkit` was the problem. Along with some help from [this article](https://mikecoutermarsh.com/rails-capybara-selenium-chrome-driver-setup/), here's what I needed to change the test passing:

Added these to my `Gemfile`:

```
group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end
```

Added this to my `test_helper.rb`:

```
class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
  end

  Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome

  Capybara.configure do |config|
    config.default_max_wait_time = 10 # seconds
    config.default_driver        = :selenium
  end
end
```

And then my test:

```
test 'Account owners can add a new product as well as options and choices' do
  visit new_product_path(as: @account_owner)
  assert_title 'Add New Product'
  assert_selector 'h1', text: 'Add New Product'
  fill_in 'product_name', :with => @new_product.name
  # Users can add product options through the nested form
  click_link 'New Option'
  within('.product_options_name') do
    first('input.form-control').set("#{@t_shirt_colors.name}")
  end
  click_link 'Add Choice'
  within('.product-option-choice') do
    first('input.form-control').set("#{@red_color_choice.name}")
  end
  click_button 'Create Product'
  assert_selector '.alert', text: 'Product was successfully created.'
end
```

Comment: Note: when there's only one input in a specific scope you can use `fill_in` without a locator - so rather than having to do `first('input.form-control').set("#{@t_shirt_colors.name}")` you can just do `fill_in(with: "#{@t_shirt_colors.name}")` which makes it clearer that you're filling in a text field as opposed to `set` which can be used on check boxes/radios/etc.  It's also better to stay away from `first` unless you really need it because the elements returned by it have some limitations.